# Java Mail API IMAP READ_ONLY folder marks mails as read

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm using Javamail API to fetch mails from server using imap.
I'm opening a folder in READ_ONLY mode and fetching messages from the server. But the mails are being marked as read. Here's the code:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore();
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, username, password);

Folder folder = store.getFolder("Inbox");
folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
IMAPFolder imapFolder = (IMAPFolder)folder;


Message[] msgs = imapFolder.getMessages(imapFolder.getMessageCount() - 5, imapFolder.getMessageCount());
```

These messages retrieved in the above code has been marked as read, even though the folder is opened in READ_ONLY mode.

How do I ensure that the mails are not marked as read ?
Thank you for your response

Comment: What are you doing after 'getMessages'?  I don't think getMessages on it's own will mark them read.

Comment: Generally it's the server that (implicitly) marks the messages as read.  It shouldn't do that if the folder is opened read-only.  But are you sure the messages are really being permanently marked as read on the server, and that the read flag isn't just being set in the current session (connection) you have with the server?

Comment: I had another IMAP Session with the same mailbox, in READ_WRITE mode, which was marking it as read.